# Knockoutjs: how to bind to the following tags setup?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, binding

I am not familiar with knockouts and JavaScript and I have managed to put some codes together. I have problems binding to this elements.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Movie", "Home", new { id ="", title = "", year="" })">
```

as well as

```
<i class="material-icons right" onclick="loadDoc('id', 'ajax')">
```

and finally I did a binding to img tag but it won't work.

```
 <img class="activat" bind="attr:{src: image}" />

 function dealModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.records = ko.observableArray();

    $.getJSON("../../Home/tabcontent?=" + url, function (data) {
        self.records(data);
    })
}
ko.applyBindings(new dealModel());
```

this is my image source: https://img.123clouds.ru/2017/03/01/poster/8866773c6824be1eda4e3caff4655120-chicago-justice-season-1.jpg

Comment: Perhaps you should also include your JS code.

Comment: I have done that

Answer (score 0):

do not believe you are using data bind correctly it should be

```
<img class="activat" data-bind="attr:{src: image}" />
```

run the snippet below

```js
function dealMode() {
  var self = this;
  this.records = ko.observableArray();
  this.image = ko.observable(
        'https://img.123clouds.ru/2017/03/01/poster/8866773c6824be1eda4e3caff4655120-chicago-justice-season-1.jpg')
}

var myViewModel = new dealMode();

$(document).ready(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<img class="activat" data-bind="attr:{src: image}" />
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I have fixed the image binding. I was missing the word data. so all I needed to do was to make it data-binding. however my main issue is to bind this <a href="@Url.Action("Movie", "Home", new { id ="", title = "", year="" })"> and this  <i class="material-icons right" onclick="loadDoc('id', 'ajax')">